# Double For Loop & If Else statement to calculate averages and store them in a matrix

Tags: r, if-statement, for-loop, matrix, mean

Here, I present a simple problem that requires a Double For Loop and an If Else statement. My first question is assistance with minor troubleshooting, and my second question is more curiosity driven in that I am interested in a shorter, more elegant solution. In the case of the first question, here is an example:

```
A<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
B<-c(2,3,4,5,6)
Q1<-data.frame(cbind(A,B))
mean<-matrix(nrow=5, ncol = 5)
for(i in 1: length(Q1$A)){
  for(j in 1: length(Q1$B)){
    if(Q1$A[i]==Q1$B[j]){
      mean[i,j]<-NA
    }else{
      mean[i,j]<-sum(Q1$A[i]+Q1$B[j])/2
    }
  }
}
```

Essentially, I have two vectors and I wish to calculate the averages of each value in Q1$A with each value in Q1$B except for when the index of Q1$A matches with the index of Q1$B (e.g. Q1$A[1]==Q1$B[1]) and then store them in a matrix.

This is what I hope to obtain:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   NA  2.0  2.5  3.0  3.5
[2,]  2.0   NA  3.0  3.5  4.0
[3,]  2.5  3.0   NA  4.0  4.5
[4,]  3.0  3.5  4.0   NA  5.0
[5,]  3.5  4.0  4.5  5.0   NA
```

However, below is my result:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]  1.5  2.0  2.5  3.0  3.5
[2,]   NA  2.5  3.0  3.5  4.0
[3,]  2.5   NA  3.5  4.0  4.5
[4,]  3.0  3.5   NA  4.5  5.0
[5,]  3.5  4.0  4.5   NA  5.5
```

Any simple solution is greatly appreciated. I would imagine a slight tweak in my ifelse statement with `mean[i,j]<-NA` or a function to skip to the next loop if `match(Q1$A[i],Q1$B[j])` would suffice.

As for my second question, I am curious if there is a simpler solution involving apply(), dplyr(), or any other packages or base R functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I reckon this is what you need:

```
A<-c(1,2,3,4,5)
B<-c(2,3,4,5,6)
Q1<-data.frame(cbind(A,B))

res <- outer(A, B, "+")/2
diag(res) <- NA
res
```

The `outer()` function does all the magic. Result:

```
     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5]
[1,]   NA  2.0  2.5  3.0  3.5
[2,]  2.0   NA  3.0  3.5  4.0
[3,]  2.5  3.0   NA  4.0  4.5
[4,]  3.0  3.5  4.0   NA  5.0
[5,]  3.5  4.0  4.5  5.0   NA
```

Comment: The travesty here is that I can't accept your answer with a green check because you answered the question too quickly and there is still a time limit. :)

Comment: It seems like you keep asking the same question over and over, and almost identical answer was already provided on your previous question....

Comment: @DavidArenburg I apologize for questions with overlapping topics. I'm just interested in several solutions to a particular problem set. I'll condense them into one post in the future!

Answer (score 4):

This is the answer to your first question about why the matrix is not working

The following line of code

```
if(Q1$A[i]==Q1$B[j]){
```

Checks the values match not if the indexes match, you need to do

```
if(i==j){
```